# newbie to postgreSQL and I am not able to load/restore sample database 'dvdrental.tar'

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I am newbie to postgreSQL. today is my first day of tutorial. I am trying to restore sample database dvdrental.tar as mentioned but the process is getting failed again and again!

Today is first day of me trying to learn postgreSQL

as mentioned on website 'postgretutorial.com' I am trying to load/restore database [dvdrental.tar](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-getting-started/postgresql-sample-database/) but the process is getting failed again and again!

My Steps :
1. Connected to server (pretty basic)

2. Created database dvdrental

3. dvdrental -> right click -> resore -> custom or tar & C:\sampledb\dvdrental.tar & postgres -> restore

and no changes in schema or I can't see any tables!

[image: dvdrental restore process failure screenshot]

here's details for process

[image]

Comment: What version of pgAdmin is this?

Comment: Please follow the instruction given on the same website (https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-getting-started/load-postgresql-sample-database/ )

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because user does not read instruction given on website.

Answer (score 0):

It got resolved after doing the following steps

Open up pgAdmin4 and go to:

File > Preferences > Paths > Binary paths > PostgreSQL Binary Path

> select the appropriate postgres version(you may not have the default version listed)
> select the bin folder of the version selected and click validate > Click OK

Answer (score 0):

Try This!

Open pgAdmin < File < Preferences < Paths < Binary Path <  and set the path to both the server path and Postgresql  path to the version you have installed and set as default . Path should be pointing to your bin directory , eg : C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\16\bin. Hope it helps!